# Get specific iFrame class with jQuery (or get CKEditor value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am getting an iFrame this way currently:

`$('body', window.parent.frames[0].document)`

This is for CKEditor, the WYSIWYG html editor.  However, I believe it dynamically adds certain other frames (not sure how).  So I rather just get a specific frame by a class name that I know will always be there (unlike the above method which will only get the first instance).

The class name is: `cke_wysiwyg_frame`

How can I do this?

(The reason is I am saving the content to my database with a button; the button needs to know where the CKEditor content is.  So far the way I am doing it is unreliable.)

**Edit**:  I decided to do it the correct way using the Ckeditor API and not my requested hack above.

Comment: Why are you not using the CKEditor api to get the content? AKA `CKEDITOR.instances.editorId.getData();`

Comment: `window.parent.getElementsByClassName('cke_wysiwyg_frame')` doesn't work?

Comment: The api seems to save using `onblur` when  you click outside of the editable area which is not what I want.

Comment: What does onblur have to do with getting the data?

Comment: @epascarello  it uses the `getData()` method like you said.  I am not sure how to use that in the context outside of the way I saw in the docs which was `event.editor.getData()` I think.  The `event` came inside a function which I am not using.

Comment: @epascarello  However, it appears the way you wrote it above is exactly what I needed.  You can add that as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from an editor instance, you can reference the instance and use [getData](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData)

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editorId.getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".cke_wysiwyg_frame").contents().find("contentIdorClass");
```

You better use `.contents()` method to get all the content of the iframe.